# Netbeans 15.0 project not downloading and running on RPi

Tags: java, execution, netbeans-12, netbeans-15

I have a Netbeans IDE 12.5 Java program (JKD 11) which compiles, downloads and runs on my RPi4. Now, with Netbeans15.0, and the exact same project, I see the compile stage successfully build the project. The "deploy" and finally "run-remote" phases do nothing. There is no attempt to connect and download and no error message. Yes, my remote platform is set in the project properties and test shows I can connect. Something in Netbeans has changed since this project works properly in Netbeans 12.5 but not 15. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also, update your question with the following: [1] The versions of Java and NetBeans being used when everything worked. [2] The versions of Java and NetBeans currently being used. [3] The content of the **Output** window in text form.